# Discount Codes By A Customer ID Or Email using Graphql

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to select discount codes assigned to a logged-in user using admin graphql API.  I am able to select all discount codes but I am not able to filter them by customer ID or customer email address. Here is my GQL. Can you guide me on how can limit the results to specified customers?

```
{
  priceRules(first: 10, reverse: true) {
    nodes {
      customerSelection {
        customers(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              email
            }
          }
        }
      }
      title
    }
  }
}
```